# MERN Stack Email Confirmation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I've been scouring the internet on how to implement Nodemailer into a MERN stack application to send an email confirmation on user login.

I've got the application setup and properly logging in / logging out users and having them authenticated through that process. However, the implementation of nodemailer, jwt tokens and the front end of react.

I've not been able to find a way to implement this into my application and am asking for any recommendations or for a point in the right direction to learn this particular functionality.

Here's the link to the github repo for a look at the code: https://github.com/sethgspivey/mern-stack-two.git

I've got the initial test code for Nodemailer to work from the index.js file in the root directory. But again, the implementation into the react front end is where I'm hung up.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in a project I built first you need to build out an endpoint that will be hit when the login is accepted something along the lines of:

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const mailer = require('../controllers/mailerController')

router
    .route('/your-end-point-here')
    .post(mailer.addToMailList)

module.exports = router
```

Notice this uses a controller that I built out. The controller will look something similar to this:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')


module.exports =
{
    addToMailList: function (req, res)
    {
        let { newUser } = req.body

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service:'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'yourcompanyemail@gmail.com',
                pass: 'somepassword'
            }

        });

        message = "You just logged in!"

        // setup email data with unicode symbols
        let mailOptions = {
            from: '"Your Company Name" <yourcompanyemail@gmail.com>', // sender address
            to: newUser, // list of receivers
            subject: "Welcome Letter", // Subject line
            text: message // plain text body
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return
                console.log(error);
            }
            res.json(info);

        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

// email data with unicode
let mailOption = {
from: '"" yourcompanyemail@gmail.com',
to: @mail,
subject: "hello ",
text: MyMessage
};

Comment: Isn't this the same solution as in [Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317617/2227743)?